# Improving time for opening QGIS project

Tags: qgis, postgresql, performance

We have a QGIS project using PostgreSQL database "made with" osm2pgsql.
The database is about 68GB.

Our Configuration is :
AMD-FX 8 cores @ 4.7Ghz
32 Gb RAM
500 Gb SSD (read/write 600Mb/s)
Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
QGIS 2.8.2

When we open the project, it takes about 10 minutes.
After that we can navigate, zoom in/out, show hide layers, all without a problem.

Is there a way to improve the time for opening the project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@AndreJ showed us the way.

First you have to know that when adding a `Layer` from your database, **the database parameters are burnt into the QGIS project file**.
This mean if you modify those parameters from QGIS source, it will not affect you project file.

If you need to modify those parameters there is only 2 solutions :

1/ Remove the layer and re-import it with correct parameters.

2/ Editing your QGIS project file with a Text Editor (our case because was many styles and scripts in the layers) and find those lines :

```
<datasource>dbname='MyDatabase' host=localhost port=5432 user='MyLog' password='MyPass'... </datasource>
```

and add `estimatedmetadata=true` in order to activate **estimated table metadata** option :

```
<datasource>dbname='MyDatabase' host=localhost port=5432 user='MyLog' password='MyPass' ... estimatedmetadata=true ... </datasource>
```

We can now open our project in few seconds instead of 10 minutes.

Comment: A third option could be to use the changeDataSource (https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/changeDataSource/) plugin to change the database parameters.